# what's suitable for private distributed repository?

Tags: version-control

I want to use distributed repository for my Hadoop project but, I want to keep it with me and my project partner for now. I know GitHub is best for this but I can't spend money. So, would anybody suggest any free alternative? What about [Bazaar from Canonical](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/)

If my question is inappropriate please suggest so.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution for this. As I'm using it for the college project, BitBucket is a good option.